# How do you get rid of � (utf8 invalid character) in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, utf-8

We have a store with lots of � characters in our product descriptions. We tried running `update queries like UPDATE {table} SET description=REPLACE(description,'�','')`
This worked in some instances but we keep finding more of them.  Anyone know an easy way to get rid of them all?

Our store is running on Volusion which uses SQL SERVER 2008, but they limit the kinds of queries you can run. If necessary, we also have an updated copy of all of the product info in a  mysql database that we can do anything we want to and upload changes.

Comment: Do you know what encodings the column is set, and in the applications (if any)? It's probably a better solution to adjust the encodings than just removing the characters.

Comment: That symbol just represents a character it can't show you in your current encoding. If you copy and paste "�" you're copying and pasting the original character value, so when you use it in your replace statement, in your columns you're replacing all instances of the original character - any other characters which it aren't representable in your current encoding are still present in the original strings.

Comment: I'm not sure about the encoding. Volusion hides all of their database details.  But when I did SET NAMES 'utf8' in our mysql copy all the characters turned out looking like they're supposed to.

Answer (score -1):

A PHP mysql connection defaults to a latin1 connection, so, your first query after connection should be:

mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

Maybe ^^

Comment: SET NAMES 'utf8' worked in mysql. The thing is before I go this route I was looking for a way inside SQL server.

Comment: @user981971 What type is the column? I suspect it's varchar, try changing it to nvarchar so it can hold unicode data.